# Android studio can not recognize manifest file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, manifest

My Android Studio Chipmunk can not recognize AndroidManifest.xml files in all projects.
Other .xml files are correctly recognized. AndroidManifest is recognized as "plain-text".
I tried to update android studio (got bumblebee before) do completely clean install and also delete and reimport projects.
Any idea what could help ?

[image: androidmanifest_file]

Comment: try File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart Android Studio. it would be helpful.

Comment: of course clean/rebuild, invalidate/restart does not help. I have this problem couple of weeks

Comment: Open Manifest file in File Explorer (NotePad) then press ctrl + s (save). then check.

Comment: it does not help

Comment: Enclose a manifest, possibly a small and simple one, so other people can try to reproduce the problem and and troubleshoot it.

Comment: it apply to any project I have, no matter where project folder is placed. Even when i create new empty project, manifest file will not be recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed after updating Android Studio to Dolphin (2021.3.1) and gradle to 7.3.0